# Why does vim sometimes show ^M and sometimes not (even if they are there)?

Tags: vim, sed, eol

I'm trying to remove all CLRF characters from a projects git repo.  I'm writing a command to grep through the repo recursively to find instances.  However, some of the 'hits' when opened in vim show very explicitly that there is ^M and yet others do not display these characters.

However, when running

```
file <filename without visual ^M>
```

It says

```
blah.java ASCII Java program text, with CRLF line terminators
```

and

```
od -cx <filename without visual ^M>
```

returns with \r\n peppered throughout.

I'm just interested why vim sometimes shows them and sometimes not.

EDIT:

I created a test text file and manually added ^M (ie ctrl V + ctrl M) and vim displayed those characters.  Then I ran:

```
sed -i '' -e 's/\r//g' controlm.txt
```

And opened the file with vim and the visual ^M were gone, but od -cx still showed \r \n, however I then ran

```
sed -i '' -e 's/^M//g' controlm.txt
```

Then it removed not only the visual ^M in vim as well as I've confirmed that od -cx displays that \r \n are now just \n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question would probably better be asked on Superuser.com, not here, because it's about using vim, not programming. But to answer it:

When opening a file, vim tries to detect if it's a MS-DOS/Windows or a unix file. If all lines are terminated by `\r\n`, it's probably a DOS file, if only some of them are, vim may assume unix as well. If the file format is set to DOS, vim ignores `\r` when reading the file, and shows [dos] in the status line directly after reading the file.

When writing back the file, it terminates each line with `\r\n`; if the file format is unix, it terminates lines with `\n`. You can set the mode with the command

```
:se fileformat=unix
```

or

```
:se fileformat=dos
```

Try creating a file `x.txt` in Windows, open it in vim. Then, `:se fileformat=unix` and `:w y.txt`;  then `:se fileformat=dos` and `:w z.txt`. Test y.txt and z.txt with `od cx`. `y.txt` will have `\r\n` line endings, `z.txt` won't.

When only some, but not all, lines in the file end in `\r`, for example if (unix) git added some headers (without `\r`) to a file that was created on dos/windows, the file format detection sees the headers first, assumes unix, does not remove the `\r` from the rest of the file when reading, and shows those as `^M`.

Comment: That's good info thanks.  I still don't fully understand why if vim sees that it is dos format (from the info bar at the bottom of vim) and the cli tool 'file' says it is a file with CRLF line terminators, and yet vim does not show ^M when the editor is opened.  Then in other files the ^M are displayed. **EDIT** Oh I see, the files where ^M are displayed has a mix of dos/unix line endings whereas as the ones that don't display ^M (but od -cx reports) have ALL CRLF endings so VI must just decide to show in 'unix' mode and proactively display the ^M

Comment: You wrote the wrong order. `y.txt` will have `\n` only while `z.txt` will have `\r\n`.

Answer (score 3):

@Guntram Blohm is right, but he left out part of the answer:  the `'fileformats'` option (short form `'ffs'`).  If you

```
:set ffs=unix
:e dosfile.txt
```

then vim will stubbornly refuse to accept the CRLF line endings and will show all the `^M` characters explicitly.

```
:help 'ffs'
```